# fetch token in a single command

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a config file which has got gitlab token in it with two different values for token, Is there a way to get that values in a single bash script command.Lokking for single line command to fetch the token.

```
concurrent = 10
check_interval = 0
[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800
[[runners]]
  name = "gitlab"
  limit = 13
  url = "gitlab url"
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  executor = "docker+machine"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:stable"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = true
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.machine]
    IdleCount = 0
    IdleTime = 300
    MaxBuilds = 600
    MachineDriver = "amazonec2"
    MachineName = "gitlab-docker-machine-%s"
    OffPeakPeriods = ["* * 0-9,17-23 * * mon-fri *", "* * * * * sat,sun *"]
    OffPeakTimezone = "Europe/London"
    OffPeakIdleCount = 0
    OffPeakIdleTime = 30
[[runners]]
  name = "gitlab"
  limit = 11
  url = "gitlab url"
  token = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
  executor = "docker+machine"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:stable"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = true
    shm_size = 0
```

Comment: Do you intend to get the two tokens in two separate variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is possible using the following command.

```
awk -F' = ' '/token/ {print $2}'  config.txt | sed -n 1p
```

OR

```
awk -F' = ' '/token/ {print $2}'  config.txt | sed -n 2p
```

OR

```
awk -F' = ' '/token/ {print $2}'  config.txt | awk 'NR==1'
```

OR

```
awk -F' = ' '/token/ {print $2}'  config.txt | awk 'NR==2'
```

Comment: IMHO, this could be done in single `awk` see this once https://stackoverflow.com/a/55578745/5866580

Comment: `awk -F" = " '/token/ && NR == 1 { print $2 }'`; why have two separate instances when you could just have two conditions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep to isolate the lines that include the token:

```
cat test  | grep token'
```

If you want just the token itself without the "token =", add awk:

```
cat test  | grep token | awk '{print $3}'
```

And if you want to get just the string of the token, without the " character, add tr:

```
cat test  | grep token | awk '{print $3}' |  tr -d \"
```

Comment: IMHO, this could be done in single `awk`, see this once https://stackoverflow.com/a/55578745/5866580

Comment: Pipelines have a performance penalty, particularly when working with small enough amounts of data that startup costs are significant as a percentage of total runtime. When you run `grep -e token test` or `grep -e token <test`, `grep` has a direct handle on the `test` file; when you run `cat test | grep -e token`, the file `test` is first read by one program (`cat`), written to its stdout, read by a second program (`grep`) on stdin, written to that program's stdout -- none of this is free.

Comment: ...granted, at least for `cat` and `grep` that penalty is fairly minor; on the other hand, `cat foo | tail` has to read all of `foo` (even if it's multiple GB or TB of data), whereas `tail foo` or `tail <foo` can skip straight to the end. Similarly, `sort <foo` can parallelize, forking into subprocesses or threads that sort different subsections of the file in parallel and then doing a merge sort to combine their results; but `cat foo | sort` can only read beginning-to-end.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done in single `awk` with more generic way. I have added a variable named `occur` here where we can mention like on which occurrence value we want to print.

```
awk -v occur="2" -F' = ' '/token/{if(++count==occur){print}}'  config.txt
```

In this case it will print value for line token's 2nd field(2nd occurrence) only.
One could change value of `occur` and could print that line's token's value.

---

---

***EDIT:*** To make it more fast in terms of processing, I am adding `exit` in my code now too, which will force awk program to exit ASAP it finds its matched string of matched occurrence.

```
awk -v occur="2" -F' = ' '/token/{if(++count==occur){print;exit}}'  config.txt
```

Comment: @Prasad Ligade, could you please try this solution once and let me know if this helps you?